# jQuery: Executing code for each element that matches a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`$("p")` references all paragraphs on the current web page. Is it possible to execute code for each element that matched the selector?

Here's a simplistic example in pseudo-code:

```
// Show the background color of every paragraph on the page
foreach (object = $("p")) {
  alert(object.css("background-color"));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('p').css('background-color', 'black')
```

If you need more flexibility:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for iterating through the matched elements, like this:

```
$("p").each(function() {
  alert($(this).css("background-color"));
});
```

If you want to *set* or *do* something (e.g. not getting a value from each like above), there's no need for [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), just execute it and it'll run for every element on the set...this is the default jQuery behavior, for example:

```
$("p").show(); //shows all <p> elements
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method sounds like what you want

```
$('p').each(function() {
    alert($(this).css('backgroundColor'));
}
```

Comment: As an aside here, `backgroundColor` is there to use as a property, like `{ backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'green' }`, but when using a string there's no need to use anything but the standard syntax (easier to find when you're debugging too).  `backgroundColor` gets transformed back to `background-color` under the covers when it runs, no need to convert it here just to create extra work :)

Comment: Ah, nice, thanks for that Nick. I use it this way out of force of habit. Must be time to break that habit :-)